# Image not responsive in one content type. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Tags: theming

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me. Yesterday, i noticed that the main image on my photo gallery content stopped behaving responsively. For example: http://thesalinepost.com/photo-gallery/saline-sweeps-tecumseh-home-opening-doubleheader Now, the same image style is working correctly on article content http://thesalinepost.com/article/saline-rowers-kick-spring-season-spring-lake-michigan
And on it's working on announcement and events content.

Answer (score 0):

Because you a style rule somewhere...

```
.node-openpublish-photo-gallery .field-name-field-op-main-image {
   width: 620px;
}
```

They appear to be different content types...

node-openpublish-photo-gallery (not working)

node-openpublish-article (working)

Comment: THank you. I've searched CSS files can can't seem to find this rule.